# How to get a file handle of a dependency in maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Does anyone know the best way to get a file handle to dependency declared in a POM? I realize that there is a dependency plugin, but we are trying to avoid the cost of copying the artifact to the local directory (The file is big).

Comment: I found a way to do this with a combination of the ArtifactFactory and ArtifactResolver classes.

Answer (score 0):

So the psuedo code would look like the following:

```
Artifact artifact = ArtifactFactory.createArtifact("group", "artifact", "version1");

// The local Repo and remote repo can be injected into your mojo using annoations.
AtifactResolver resolver = new AtifactResolver(localRepo, remoteRepoList);

resolver.resolve(artificat);

File file = artifact.getFile();
```